# How to change storyboard animation when user toggles a switch on the UI for UWP Apps?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP App where I have 2 images and a toggle switch. When the toggle switch is in the default(off state), I would want one image to show and when the user toggles the switch, I want the second image to show. My understanding is that I should be using a grid with 2 images stacked one upon the other and based on the toggle switch position, I should use storyboarding and move the images. Is there a better way to do this example using visual states property of storyboard? Can I use the VisualManager of storyboards to animate the same property i.e transition of the 2 images in my UI?I would learn to learn better ways to achieve this animation using MVVM and Prism.

Comment: From your problem description, I can understand your intentions, but there are some things I want to confirm with you. Could you tell me if you want to display only the second picture or two pictures when switching? 
You mentioned MVVM, but this is not involved in this question (or you can do some simple transformations, such as moving event callbacks from code-behind to ViewModel), do you accept the normal VisualState code snippet in XAML and switching VisualState in ToggleSwitch.Toggled event (code-behind)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For your first question, i would like picture A to be displayed when toggled off and picture B when toggled on. I mentioned MVVM to have a possibility to control the storyboard from the View model as opposed to the code behind. And I didnt quite understand the last question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch pictures when the status of the ToggleSwitch control changes by using the visual states property of storyboard, you can add two visual states to change the Opacity of Image control in the Grid, for example:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="state1">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="state2">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>

            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="image1" Source="Assets/11.png" Opacity="100"/>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="image2" Source="Assets/22.png" Opacity="0"/>

    <ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch" IsOn="False" Grid.Row="1" Toggled="toggleSwitch_Toggled">
        
    </ToggleSwitch>
</Grid>
```

Call the VisualStateManager.GoToState() to switch the state when the status of ToggleSwitch control changes, like this:

```
private void toggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(toggleSwitch.IsOn==true)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "state1", false);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "state2", false);
    }
}
```